# min heap in python

Tags: python, object, heap, min-heap

I'd like to store a set of objects in a min heap by defining a custom comparison function.  I see there is a heapq module available as part of the python distribution.  Is there a way to use a custom comparator with this module?  If not, has someone else built a custom min heap?

Comment: For a more confortable snippet - (and Python 3 ready), check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875706/python-heapq-with-custom-compare-predicate/8875823#8875823

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Define a wrapping class that implements your custom comparator, and use a list of those instead of a list of your actual objects. That's about the best there is while still using the heapq module, since it provides no key= or cmp= arguments like the sorting functions/methods do.

```
def gen_wrapper(cmp):
    class Wrapper(object):
        def __init__(self, value): self.value = value
        def __cmp__(self, obj): return cmp(self.value, obj.value)
    return Wrapper
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in python 3.0, which gets rid of __cmp__ .

Comment: No, it won't work in Python 3.0, but that doesn't matter, because Python 3.0 lacks the entire concept of "comparator function". The question simply doesn't apply in that case.

Comment: Um. You should define __le__ rather than __cmp__. That would keep the Python 2/3 compatibility. After all, heapq operations and sort operations use <= as their comparison function.

Comment: I don't care about python 3.0 compatibility. Python 3.0 is still not commonly used, and writing 2/3 quines is difficult and ultimately futile. The most pythonic way to define this in 2.x is as I wrote above. Python 3.0 is backwards incompatible, and what's best in 2.x may not work. Too bad.

Answer (score 16):

Two options (aside from Devin Jeanpierre's suggestion):

1. Decorate your data before using the heap.  This is the equivalent of the `key=` option to sorting.  e.g. if you (for some reason) wanted to heapify a list of numbers according to their sine:

   ```
   data = [ # list of numbers ]
   heap = [(math.sin(x), x) for x in data]
   heapq.heapify(heap)
   # get the min element
   item = heappop(heap)[1]
   ```
2. The `heapq` module is implemented in pure python.  You could just copy it to your working directory and change the relevant bits.  From a quick look, you would have to modify siftdown() and siftup(), and possibly nlargest and nsmallest if you need them.

Comment: Also, the heapq module is implemented both in C and in Python. Importing heapq uses the C module if available.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Well, the important thing for my second suggestion is that python code is available in your lib directory if you want to roll your own.

Comment: I think this is the better solution. It actually takes less code, and is probably faster, since you're using the built-in tuple type instead of defining your own class.