# heapq with custom compare predicate

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, containers

I am trying to build a heap with a custom sort predicate. Since the values going into it are of "user-defined" type, I cannot modify their built-in comparison predicate.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
h = heapq.heapify([...], key=my_lt_pred)
h = heapq.heappush(h, key=my_lt_pred)
```

Or even better, I could wrap the `heapq` functions in my own container so I don't need to keep passing the predicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679731/min-heap-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make heapq evaluate the heap off of a specific attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954530/how-to-make-heapq-evaluate-the-heap-off-of-a-specific-attribute)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

According to the [heapq documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html), the way to customize the heap order is to have each element on the heap to be a tuple, with the first tuple element being one that accepts  normal Python comparisons.

The functions in the heapq module are a bit cumbersome (since they are not object-oriented), and always require our heap object (a heapified list) to be explicitly passed as the first parameter. We can kill two birds with one stone by creating a very simple wrapper class that will allow us to specify a `key` function, and present the heap as an object.

The class below keeps an internal list, where each element is a tuple, the first member of which is a key, calculated at element insertion time using the `key` parameter, passed at Heap instantiation:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import heapq

class MyHeap(object):
    def __init__(self, initial=None, key=lambda x:x):
        self.key = key
        self.index = 0
        if initial:
            self._data = [(key(item), i, item) for i, item in enumerate(initial)]
            self.index = len(self._data)
            heapq.heapify(self._data)
        else:
            self._data = []

    def push(self, item):
        heapq.heappush(self._data, (self.key(item), self.index, item))
        self.index += 1

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self._data)[2]
```

(The extra `self.index` part is to avoid clashes when the evaluated key value is a draw and the stored value is not directly comparable - otherwise heapq could fail with TypeError)

Comment: Very nice! You could even go further and use triples (self.key(item), id, item), where id could be an integer handled as a class attribute, and incremented after each push. That way, you avoid the exception raised when key(item1) = key(item2). Because keys would be unique.

Comment: I actually tried to push this (or something based on this) into Python's stdlib,and the suggestion got declined.

Comment: pity, fits the object-oriented style of most Python features, and the key argument provides extra flexibility.

Comment: I have used list instead of tuple for e.g. [self.key(item), id, item] and it works just fine as long as first index is key.

Comment: @DeepakYadav things might go messy, as lists are mutable, and tuples are not. If you'll change the priority (the [0]) the heap will be broken.

Comment: @jsbueno  sorry for a stupid question but I'm new to python and looking at your example, I don't see how the custom predicate is defined.  Shouldn't there be some function that defines a strict weak less than ordering?  I assume self.key(item) is used to for the predicate is this is where you can define custom behavior but you just returned the value as is in your example, correct?  But I don't see how to consume this when you need a custom ordering, like for example if you want to order based on both values of pair you'll need to have a comparison of two pairs and return a true/false for <.

Comment: The `key` argument should be a callable object (ex. a function), that taking the main item as input, yields another object that is directly comparable by Python with `>` and `<=` in the desired order. The idea is the same of the `key` parameter on the  built-in `sorted` method - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: This would fail if elements are not comparable and there are ties in key values. I'd put `id(item)` as a middle element of the tuple to break ties.

Comment: @GeorgiYanchev - I added that now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think the more specified way to do this is to use https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering

Answer (score 161):

Define a class, in which override the `__lt__()` function. See example below (works in Python 3.7):

```py
import heapq

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node value: {self.val}'

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val < other.val

heap = [Node(2), Node(0), Node(1), Node(4), Node(2)]
heapq.heapify(heap)
print(heap)  # output: [Node value: 0, Node value: 2, Node value: 1, Node value: 4, Node value: 2]

heapq.heappop(heap)
print(heap)  # output: [Node value: 1, Node value: 2, Node value: 2, Node value: 4]
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution by far!

Comment: Absolutely agree with the previous two comments. This seems to be a better, cleaner solution for Python 3.

Comment: Also, here is very similar solution to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python/40455775?noredirect=1#comment110575517_40455775

Comment: I tested this using `__gt__` instead and it works as well. Why doesn't it matter which magic method we use? I can't find anything in `heapq`'s documentation. Maybe it's related to how Python does comparisons in general?

Comment: When doing a comparison in `heapq`, Python looks for `__lt__()` first. If it is not defined, it will look for `__gt__()`. If neither is defined, it throws `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'`. This can be confirmed by defining both `__lt__()` and `__gt__()`, placing a print statement in each, and having `__lt__()` return `NotImplemented`.

Comment: To make this solution a complete one, there needs to be a tie breaker. In order to break the tie when "self.val == other.val" in the "__lt__" function, one option is to introduce an other field (priority or something that is pertinent to your business domain) into Node class, so that we could compare this field and make sure there are not equal values regarding this field.

Answer (score 29):

The [heapq documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) suggests that heap elements could be tuples in which the first element is the priority and defines the sort order.

More pertinent to your question, however, is that the documentation includes a [discussion with sample code](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) of how one could implement their own heapq wrapper functions to deal with the problems of sort stability and elements with equal priority (among other issues).

In a nutshell, their solution is to have each element in the heapq be a triple with the priority, an entry count and the element to be inserted. The entry count ensures that elements with the same priority a sorted in the order they were added to the heapq.

Comment: This is the correct solution, both heappush and heappushpop works directly with tuples

Comment: this solution is clean but can not cover all custom algorithm, for example, a max heap of string.

Comment: i really don't understand how people find submitting an entry count a clean solution. gods of python hear my prayers and make a normal priority queue class. thanks!

Answer (score 27):

```
setattr(ListNode, "__lt__", lambda self, other: self.val <= other.val)
```

Use this for comparing values of objects in heapq

Comment: Interesting way to avoid redefining/re-encapsulating the object!

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Though this may work for `Leetcode`, this doesn't work with `heapq`

Comment: Thanks, this answer deserves to be at the top

Answer (score 3):

The limitation with both answers is that they don't allow ties to be treated as ties.  In the first, ties are broken by comparing items, in the second by comparing input order.  It is faster to just let ties be ties, and if there are a lot of them it could make a big difference.  Based on the above and on the docs, it is not clear if this can be achieved in heapq.  It does seem strange that heapq does not accept a key, while functions derived from it in the same module do.
P.S.:
If you follow the link in the first comment ("possible duplicate...") there is another suggestion of defining le which seems like a solution.

Comment: The limitation with writing "both answers" is that it is no longer clear which those are.

Answer (score 2):

Simple little trick:

Say you have this list of (name,age) as

```
a = [('Tim',4), ('Radha',9), ('Rob',7), ('Krsna',3)]
```

And you want to sort this list based on their ageby adding them to a min-heap, instead of writing all the custom comparator stuff, you can just flip the order of the contents of the tuple just before pushing it to the queue. This is because heapq.heappush() sorts by the first element of the tuple by default.
Like this:

```
import heapq
heap = []
heapq.heapify(heap)
for element in a:
    heapq.heappush(heap, (element[1],element[0]))
```

This is a simple trick if this does your job and you don't want to get into writing the custom comparator mess.

Similarly it sorts the values in ascending order by default. If you want to sort in descending order of age, flip the contents and make the value of the first element of the tuple a negative:

```
import heapq
heap = []
heapq.heapify(heap)
for element in a:
    heapq.heappush(heap, (-element[1],element[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In python3, you can use `cmp_to_key` from `functools` module. [cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7ad52d174a12951d260aecfcdfe0fcfd2437a66b/Lib/functools.py#L206).

Suppose you need a priority queue of triplets and specify the priority use the last attribute.

```py
from heapq import *
from functools import cmp_to_key
def mycmp(triplet_left, triplet_right):
    key_l, key_r = triplet_left[2], triplet_right[2]
    if key_l > key_r:
        return -1  # larger first
    elif key_l == key_r:
        return 0  # equal
    else:
        return 1


WrapperCls = cmp_to_key(mycmp)
pq = []
myobj = tuple(1, 2, "anystring")
# to push an object myobj into pq
heappush(pq, WrapperCls(myobj))
# to get the heap top use the `obj` attribute
inner = pq[0].obj
```

### Performance Test:

#### Environment

python 3.10.2

#### Code

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key
from timeit import default_timer as time
from random import randint
from heapq import *

class WrapperCls1:
    __slots__ = 'obj'
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __lt__(self, other):
        kl, kr = self.obj[2], other.obj[2]
        return True if kl > kr else False

def cmp_class2(obj1, obj2):
    kl, kr = obj1[2], obj2[2]
    return -1 if kl > kr else 0 if kl == kr else 1

WrapperCls2 = cmp_to_key(cmp_class2)

triplets = [[randint(-1000000, 1000000) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(100000)]
# tuple_triplets = [tuple(randint(-1000000, 1000000) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(100000)]

def test_cls1():
    pq = []
    for triplet in triplets:
        heappush(pq, WrapperCls1(triplet))
        
def test_cls2():
    pq = []
    for triplet in triplets:
        heappush(pq, WrapperCls2(triplet))

def test_cls3():
    pq = []
    for triplet in triplets:
        heappush(pq, (-triplet[2], triplet))

start = time()
for _ in range(10):
    test_cls1()
    # test_cls2()
    # test_cls3()
print("total running time (seconds): ", -start+(start:=time()))
```

#### Results

use `list` instead of `tuple`, per function:

- WrapperCls1: 16.2ms
- WrapperCls1 with `__slots__`: 9.8ms
- WrapperCls2: 8.6ms
- move the priority attribute into the first position ( don't support **custom** predicate ): 6.0ms.

Therefore, this method is slightly faster than using a custom class with an overridden `__lt__()` function and the `__slots__` attribute.

Comment: Have you check those results? I got something like`[<functools.KeyWrapper> ...]` instead of the value.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Did you forget to use the `.obj` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple and Recent

A simple solution is to `store entries as a list of tuples` for each tuple define the priority in your desired order if you need a different order for each item within the tuple just make it the negative for descending order.

See the official heapq python documentation in this topic [Priority Queue Implementation Notes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from [Fanchen Bao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9723036/fanchen-bao) above, I created a **Max Priority Queue** by extending tuple:

```
import heapq

class MaxTuple(tuple):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self[0] > other[0]

my_tuples = [(2, "orange"), (1, "red"), (5, "blue"), (3, "yellow"), (4, "green")]

my_queue = [MaxTuple(t) for t in my_tuples]

heapq.heapify(my_queue)
while my_queue:
    print(heapq.heappop(my_queue))
```

Which pops the heap from max to min:

```
(5, 'blue')
(4, 'green')
(3, 'yellow')
(2, 'orange')
(1, 'red')
```