# How to heapify by field from custom objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am receiving on server objects from clients ( every object has same structure and have field self.utc_time which contains time of creation of that object). I need to store in some structure so I always have sorted in ascending so when I pop I pop the oldest object by utc_time, not by time when I receive. I thought to use priority queue from heapq but how to say to heaify by utc_time field from custom objects ? Is there better solution ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add the [magic `__cmp__` comparison method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) to your class to avoid needing to do the tuple-decoration that Maksim describes:

## Python 3

```
>>> import heapq
>>> class MyObject(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.val < other.val
```

## Python 2

```
>>> import heapq
>>> class MyObject(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __cmp__(self, other):
...         return cmp(self.val, other.val)
```

Code Runner:

```
>>> q = []
>>> heapq.heappush(q, MyObject(50))
>>> heapq.heappush(q, MyObject(40))
>>> heapq.heappush(q, MyObject(30))
>>> heapq.heappush(q, MyObject(20))
>>> heapq.heappush(q, MyObject(200))
>>> obj = heapq.heappop(q)
>>> print obj.val
20
```

Note: Override **`__lt__`** in **Python 3**, `__cmp__` only in Python 2

Answer (score 9):

[Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) implicitly provides the following solution:

> Heap elements can be tuples. This is useful for assigning comparison
>   values (such as task priorities) alongside the main record being
>   tracked:

```
 h = []
 heappush(h, (5, 'write code'))
 heappush(h, (7, 'release product'))
 heappush(h, (1, 'write spec'))
 heappush(h, (3, 'create tests'))
 heappop(h)
   => (1, 'write spec')
```

You can do it in a similar fashion - store tuples where the first element will contain a `utc_time` of an object being placed to the PQ and the second - a reference to object itself.

In a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875823/276274) it's proposed to create an easy-to-use wrapper that would allow a cleaner way of working with a priority queue.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the first element of the tuple will be used as the key? How are tuples compared?

Comment: @information_interchange For sorting tuple, Python firstly sorts on the first element of the tuple, and then breaks any ties by sorting on the second element.