# In python, how should I implement a min heap on a list of tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, heap, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement a min heap on a list of tuple.
For example:

```
A=[('a',2),('b',1)]
```

how can I heapify A based on the second element of these tuple, so that A will be heapified to `[('b',1),('a',2)]` ? (I must maintain a min heap.)

Comment: What did you try? Please post your attempt.

Comment: If you are specifying an exact ordering of all the items, then you are *not dealing with a heap*.  In an actual heap, only the root item has a fixed location.

Comment: well, that is just an example. Just wanna maintain a min heap based on the second element of tuple on such a data structure.

Comment: You'll use Python's heapq, and follow the advice given in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875706/heapq-with-custom-compare-predicate. Basically, create tuples like `(2, ('a', 2))` and `(1, ('b', 1))`.

Answer (score 5):

As per @JimMischel's comment, place your tuples in a tuple with the priority as the first element.  Then use `heapq`:

```
import heapq

list = [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 0), ('d', 1)]
heap_elts = [(item[1], item) for item in list]
heapq.heapify(heap_elts)  # you specifically asked about heapify, here it is!
while len(heap_elts) > 0:
    print(heapq.heappop(heap_elts)[1])    # element 1 is the original tuple
```

produces:

```
('c', 0)
('b', 1)
('d', 1)
('a', 2)
```

Comment: someone trying for max heap can try this - heap_elts = [(item[1]*-1, item) for item in list]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import heapq

A=[('a',2),('b',1), ('d', 0), ('c', 2), ('a', 2)]
h = []
for el in A:
    heapq.heappush(h, (el[1], el[0]))

print(h)
```

result:

```
[(0, 'd'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'a')]
```