# Python Specifying Custom HeapSort Sorting Algorithms

Tags: python, heap

I have a lists of lists with two elements `[A,B]`. Firstly I want my heap to be defined in terms of `A` but in the case `A = A` I would like to compare `B` in decreasing order. But heapsort understandably also compares the `B` in increasing order when I want it in decreasing order, so ill get something like this

```
[7, 1]
[7, 0]
[6, 1]
[5, 2]
[5, 0]
[4, 4]
```

When I want this

```
[7, 0]
[7, 1]
[6, 1]
[5, 0]
[5, 2]
[4, 4]
```

How could I accomplish this?

For reference I'm using `heapq._heapify_max`

The official python solution recommends turning everything into a tuple where the first element is the one I want the sort priority on, but since I want my sort to be done on a combination of two keys this will not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heapq with custom compare predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875706/heapq-with-custom-compare-predicate)

Comment: Just run a bubble sort using both values with your own comparison logic over the heap-sorted list. Not the perfect solution, but it seems there is no better for that module

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow bubble sort would be too costly for the time constraints. I just used a stable sorting algorithm and ran over it twice. I know there are other ways to solve the problem I was just wondering if there was a standard python solution for this

Comment: Would bubble sort be costly on a pre-sorted list? I thought it performs very well in cuch cases...

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow I can't think of any case in which bubble sort will outperform insertion sort. Yes, both are O(n^2) algorithms, but insertion sort is generally faster in real world applications. But you're right, both of those algorithms perform well with pre-sorted lists.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Why would you need to go over the list twice to sort it? Can't your comparison function compare the first element and, if they're equal, compare the second? I don't see how making two passes over the list will sort it correctly.

Comment: @JimMischel I used a stable sorting algorithm so the relative ordering stayed the same over both iterations

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow the list isn't pre sorted. The list I was showing was a representation of the heap I constructed

Comment: @JimMischel check out this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort for more information