# Python PriorityQueue Heapify Method

Tags: python, heap, priority-queue

I am using this library for a heap:

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue
```

I need to trigger a heapify because in this priority queue i am inserting a node class and the prioirty queue is ordered based on node.val like this:

```
class Node():
   __init__(self,val,text):
       self.val = val
       self.text = text
```

and my pq:

```
pq = PriorityQueue()
first = Node(1,'abcd')
pq.put((first.val,first))

xyz = Node(10,'asdf')
pq.put((xyz.val,xyz))


fsa = Node(7,'asdsbcd')
pq.put((fsa.val,fsa))
```

now it works fine but if i want to for example change first nodes value like this:

```
first.val = 100
```

is there a method like pq.heapify() or something..

how do i call a heapify method so that it can sort it? because if i dont then it will be sort the list and assume first still is 1 not 100.

Comment: standard heap classes usually have only the methods for insertion, top lookup and top removal, i.e. the modification of the internal data structure is not allowed. you will need to implement your own priority queue

Comment: @mangusta hmmm, what about a remove a certain node? is there a method? so that i can remove it and then reinsert it with the updated val.

Comment: that came to my mind as well, but I'm not sure if there is such a method in python. Java's priority queue has a method `remove(Object o)`

Comment: I'm not sure if this library can do that. However, consider the heapify method from the heapq library Python provides: https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be better to use [heapq library](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html) for your heap.

Then you can use a process from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875706/heapq-with-custom-compare-predicate) to update the min value in the heap as follows.

**Advantages:**

1. Approach allows updating smallest element using replace.
2. Takes only O(log(n)) to update the value of the smallest element (i.e. changing first from 1 to 100)
3. Faster than using Heapify when only one item needs to be updated (which takes O(n))

**Code**

```
import heapq

class Node():
  def __init__(self,val,text):
       self.val = val 
       self.text = text
  def __str__(self):   # Add a method to node to string for display
    return f'{self.val}, {self.text}'

class MyHeap(object):
  """The class keeps an internal list, where each element is a tuple.
    The first tuple element is the priority (val), calculated at element insertion 
    time, using the key parameter, passed at Heap instantiation"""
  def __init__(self, initial=None, key=lambda x:x.val):
    self.key = key
    if initial:
      self._data = [(key(item), item) for item in initial]
      heapq.heapify(self._data)
    else:
      self._data = []

  def push(self, item):
    heapq.heappush(self._data, (self.key(item), item))

  def pop(self):
    return heapq.heappop(self._data)[1]

  def replace(self, item):
    # Pops min element and adds a new element
    v = self.pop()
    self.push(item)
    return v
```

**Testing**

Test 1. Add Elements and dump heap

```
# Add elements
pq = MyHeap()
first = Node(1,'abcd')
pq.push(first)

xyz = Node(10,'asdf')
pq.push(xyz)

fsa = Node(7,'asdsbcd')
pq.push(fsa)

# Dump elements in order
print('Initial Ordering')
while pq._data:
  print(pq.pop())
```

*Result*

```
Initial Ordering
1, abcd
7, asdsbcd
10, asdf
```

Test 2. Remove smallest and add as new element with larger value with new value

```
# Add elements
pq.push(first)
pq.push(xyz)
pq.push(fsa)

# Update first element using replace
first.val = 100
pq.replace(first)

print('\nNew Ordering')
while pq._data:
  print(pq.pop())
```

*Result*

```
New Ordering
7, asdsbcd
10, asdf
100, abcd
```

*Test 3: Add Elements as List*

```
print('\nUsing List')
pq = MyHeap([first, xyz, fsa])
while pq._data:
  print(pq.pop())
```

*Result*

```
Using List
7, asdsbcd
10, asdf
100, abcd
```

Comment: ill accept urs since it looks fast, but i did something a bit different, easier to code tho - i just deleted the whole heap and put it in an array, and then rebuilt the heap making sure the new value is updated.

Comment: @asdadasdasd -- The issue is modifying an element the way you mention takes O(n) time (i.e. since Heapify is O(n)).  Performing an update using the method suggested here takes O(log(n)) which is much faster.  Meaning for n ~10^6, the above method is ~20, while using Heapify ~O(n^6), which is 50,00 times slower.  However, if you're not doing this very often or the number of elements is small then it doesn't matter.

Comment: yeah but im not on leetcode - school work - so less coding for me is better.

Comment: @asdadasdasd-- As the [Zen of Python says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Simple is better than complex".  So if your technique works and is simpler to code then yes, it's better to use it.  More complex code is required only for more complex problems.